# Parse numbers and parentheses from a String?

Tags: java

Given a `String` containing numbers (possibly with decimals), parentheses and any amount of whitespace, I need to iterate through the `String` and handle each number and parenthesis.

The below works for the `String` `"1 ( 2 3 ) 4"`, but does not work if I remove whitespaces between the parentheses and the numbers `"1 (2 3) 4)"`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(expression);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String token = scanner.next();
    // handle token ...
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

Comment: If you need real parsing you may want to look into ANTLR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanner uses whitespace as it's default delimiter. You can change this to use a different Regex pattern, for example:

```
(?:\\s+)|(?<=[()])|(?=[()])
```

This pattern will set the delimiter to the left bracket or right bracket or one or more whitespace characters. However, it will also keep the left and right brackets (as I think you want to include those in your parsing?) but not the whitespace.

Here is an example of using this:

```
String test = "123(3 4)56(7)";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(test);
scanner.useDelimiter("(?:\\s+)|(?<=[()])|(?=[()])");
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

Output:

```
123
(
3
4
)
56
(
7
)
```

Detailed Regex Explanation:

```
(?:\\s+)|(?<=[()])|(?=[()])
    1st Alternative: (?:\\s+)
        (?:\\s+) Non-capturing group
            \\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    2nd Alternative: (?<=[()])
        (?<=[()]) Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matched
            [()] match a single character present in the list below
                () a single character in the list () literally
    3rd Alternative: (?=[()])
        (?=[()]) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
            [()] match a single character present in the list below
                () a single character in the list () literally
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for, except it will need to delimit (and preserve) on a couple other characters as well, say `a` and `b`. Could you explain your regex a bit, it's pretty dense for me? or give an example how to expand it to also delimit and preserve on `a` and `b`?

Comment: For "123 (3 4) 56( 7)"
this outputs "123" "(" "3" "4" ")" " 56" "(" " 7" ")"

Comment: @ab11 to match and preserve other characters you would just add them to the two character classes that currently contain just brackets `[()]`

Comment: thanks, but I'm not able to get this to work for the characters + and *. The following prints `10+` but I'd expect it to print `(` `10` `+` `*` `5` `)`     `String delimiter = "\"(?:\\\\s+)|(?<=[()+*])|(?=[()+*])\"";
        String input = "(10+ 4   * 5)";
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(expression);
        scanner.useDelimiter(delimiter);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String token = scanner.next();
            System.out.println(token);`

Comment: @ab11 It works fine, the Regex pattern you have commented with though is not the same. It should look like: `scanner.useDelimiter("(?:\\s+)|(?<=[()+*])|(?=[()+*])");` You have `\\\\S+` instead of `\\S+` and you also have a `\"` at the start and end of the expression.

Comment: arizzle. You're right, that works for me. thanks for all the help

Comment: @arizzle: do you really need that non-capturing group? after all, groups are nowhere used in this example, is `(\\s+)` not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Scanner's `.next()` method uses whitespace as its delimiter. Luckily, we can change the delimiter!

For example, if you need the scanner to process to handle whitespace and parentheses, you could run this code immediately after constructing your Scanner:

```
scanner.useDelimiter(" ()");
```